# How to split a JSON array into chunks in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: arrays, json, azure-logic-apps

My Logic App (see image below) is outlined as:

**1)** Takes data from a CSV file (file content connector)

**2)** Converts it into JSON format (through the HTTPTriggerC# Azure Function & Parse JSON)

**3)** Joins the JSON objects into a continuous JSON string (each object separated by a comma

**4)** Sends the JSON object array through the Send Data connector

The problem is that the Send Data Connector can only handle 30 MB posts at a time. As such, I need to divide my JSON object array into 30 MB arrays and sequentially post them.  I'm not sure how to do this through Logic Apps.  I assume there would be some connector, function or action between step 3) and 4). I would also need to ensure that I'm dividing my array into small enough chunks to stay under 30 MB, but also not over-divide and have the Logic App run for an hour.

Any ideas?

[My_Logic_App_Workflow.img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY8rW.png)

Comment: Sorry, some of those steps don't make sense.  Does #3 result in valid JSON?  Comma separated entities wouldn't normally be valid.

Comment: @Johns-305 Example output of #3:
{ "body": "{\"Column1\":val1,\"Column2\":\"val1\",\"Column3\":\"val2 \"}
, {\"Column1\":val1,\"Column2\":\"val2\",\"Column3\":\"val3\"}"}

Comment: So, it's just JSON then.  The extra description makes it a bit ambiguous.